# rpmbuild fails | Missing dependencies (However missing dependencies are installed)

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm attempting to build RPM's & Repo's for various agent's we use at my company. This particular package has a private library and I'm unable to figure out what the problem is.

The package seems to build just fine, however I get the following error:

```
[root@test ~]# rpm -ivh rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/ir-agent-1-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6 is needed by ir-agent-1-1.el8.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by ir-agent-1-1.el8.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by ir-agent-1-1.el8.x86_64
        libdl.so.2 is needed by ir-agent-1-1.el8.x86_64
```

glib-2.28-164.el8.x86_64 is installed on the system, so I'm unclear on what the issue is.

The following is the spec file I am using:

```
[root@test ~]# cat rpmbuild/SPECS/ir-agent-1.0.spec
Name:           ir-agent
Version:        1
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        Rapid7 Insight Agent
Group:          Application/Other
License:        BSD
URL:            www.rapid7.com
Source0:        %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
BuildArch:      x86_64
BuildRequires:  systemd
Requires:  glibc
 
 
%description
Aires installation of Rapid7 Insight Agent.
 
%global debug_package %{nil}
%global __provides_exclude_from $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/insight_agent/3.1.3.80/lib/.*\\.so$
 
%prep
%setup -q
 
%build
 
%install
#%{__mkdir} -p %{buildroot}%{base_install_dir}
#%{__install} -D -m 755 %{SOURCE0}
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/lib/systemd/{system,system-preset}
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/network_sensor/{0,common}
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/insight_agent/{3.1.3.80,common}
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/bootstrap/{2.4.0.5,common,ssl}
 
cp 90-ir-agent.preset $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/
cp ir-agent.service $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/lib/systemd/system/
cp config.json $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/insight_agent/common/
cp client.{key,crt} $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/bootstrap/ssl/
cp cafile.pem $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/bootstrap/ssl/
cp -r local/* $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/insight_agent/3.1.3.80/
cp local/bootstrap $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/rapid7/ir_agent
mv local/bootstrap $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/insight_agent/3.1.3.80/ir_agent
ln -s /opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/insight_agent/3.1.3.80/ir_agent $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/insight_agent/insight_agent
 
%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
 
%post
%systemd_post ir-agent.service
 
%preun
%systemd_preun ir-agent.service
 
%postun
%systemd_postun_with_restart ir-agent.service
 
%files
%defattr(600,root,root,751)
%dir /opt/rapid7/ir_agent
%config %attr(600, root, root) /opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/insight_agent/common/config.json
%attr(600, root, root) /opt/rapid7/ir_agent/*
%ghost /opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/insight_agent/insight_agent
%attr(700, root, root) /opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/insight_agent/3.1.3.80/bootstrap
%attr(700, root, root) /opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/insight_agent/3.1.3.80/bootstrap_upgrader
%attr(700, root, root) /opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/insight_agent/3.1.3.80/connectivity_test
%attr(700, root, root) /opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/insight_agent/3.1.3.80/get_proxy
%attr(700, root, root) /opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/insight_agent/3.1.3.80/ir_agent
%attr(700, root, root) /opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/insight_agent/3.1.3.80/token_handler
%attr(700, root, root) /opt/rapid7/ir_agent/components/insight_agent/3.1.3.80/upgrade_agent
%attr(644, root, root) /usr/lib/systemd/system/ir-agent.service
%attr(644, root, root) /usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/90-ir-agent.preset
 
%doc
 
%changelog
* Sat Mar 5 2022 
- release 1.0 - initial release
```

I haven't done too much with building RPM's, so I'm unclear as to what else to do beyond defining "Requires".

Comment: Hi Mose. It seems that your package `ir-agent` requires `glibc.i686` version. You can install this using `dnf install glibc.i686`.

Comment: If a missing module was required for the `x86` architecture (this 64-bit)  it would require `libdl.so.2()(64bit)` . Mind the `(64bit)` there. Using `dnf provides \*libbdl.so\*`  would give you exactly that.

Comment: @valentinBajrami, How were you able to identify that the 32 bit package was the culprit. Also, how do I explicitly define the 32 bit requirement in the SPEC file?

Lastly, you should post an answer to the question so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your package `ir-agent` requires `glibc.i686` version. You can install this using

```
dnf install glibc.i686
```

If a missing module was required for the x86 architecture (this 64-bit) it would require `libdl.so.2()(64bit)` . Mind the **(64bit)** there.

Using

```
dnf provides \*libbdl.so\*
```

would give you exactly that.

To answer your question regarding how to explicitly specify the `i686` version you can use exactly that (The package name as is). For example

```
Requires:  glibc.i686
```

This is also possible:

```
Requires: /lib/libc.so.6
```

This works just the same way as you'd for example use `yum` or `dnf` to install a package. For example

```
dnf install */bin/lsof
```

.. would install the `.rpm` package that provides this binary.

Hint:  Use `mock` if you are building rpm packages.

Want to know more about rpm packaging: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/create-rpm-package